# How do I create a one dimensional bar chart in excel where the lower and upper bounds are a part of the data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have this set of data values:

| description | value |
| --- | --- |
| Last 7 Days | 1.80 |
| YTD | 2.03 |
| Upper | 2.40 |
| Lower | 1.70 |

I'd like to create a one dimensional bar chart that reads the upper and lower values and uses those as end points, and plots the remaining values (in the event that "data" falls outside the upper and lower bounds, I'd like to display that as well.  Ideally the formatting would highlight the target range (upper & lower bounds) and then show data markers that were inside and outside the target.  The end result (ignoring formatting, labeling, relative distances as I created this in PPTX) would look something like this (note, no values outside the target in the example):

[image: one-dimensional bar chart]

Perhaps there is another name for this and I'm not using the correct description?

Edit:  I would need to be able to add *n* number of values

Comment: You could create a stacked bar chart and then create custom labels such as "1.85, Last 7 Days". It would look different from your desired output, but might work for you.

Comment: I've never done this, but over the years I have seen many, many applications for formulaic control over a chart's axis.  Without exception, it has always resulted in resorting to a VBA script to accomplish.  You definitely can set the minimum and maximum values through VBA and the object model, but I have never seen it accomplished using excel formulas.